# install tar.gz with pip at requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, requirements.txt

i want to install electrum-ltc into my app like this:

but if i include this line in my requirements.txt the role-out fails and i have to install it manually with the same line shown above.

if i install it like this at the requirements.txt:

some modules do not get installed in that specific case its the script package.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can accept it as answer because I "cheated" in a way.

I did:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/tgz-install && cd /tmp/tgz-install 
$ pipenv install https://download.electrum.org/3.3.3/Electrum-3.3.3.tar.gz\#egg\=electrum\[fast\]
$ pipenv shell 
$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
```

I got:

```
aiohttp==3.5.4
aiohttp-socks==0.2.2
aiorpcX==0.10.4
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==18.2.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
dnspython==1.16.0
ecdsa==0.13
Electrum==3.3.3
idna==2.8
jsonrpclib-pelix==0.4.0
multidict==4.5.2
protobuf==3.6.1
pyaes==1.6.1
pycryptodomex==3.7.3
QDarkStyle==2.5.4
qrcode==6.1
six==1.12.0
yarl==1.3.0
```

I suppose you can do everything with just `pip`.

In case you can't use `pipenv` directly - you can use created `requirements`.

Inform in case you have some trouble.

Comment: Sounds good :D i guess this works for electrum as well as for electrum-ltc

Comment: Good if it works for you. It was just too booooring to use `pip` when you have `pipenv`